# The multiplicity of $X$ at $x$ does not change when $X$ is cut by a generic hypersurface: what are those generic conditions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Given an algebraic variety $X$ with a point $x \in X$, the *multiplicity* of $X$ at $x$ is defined as the multiplicity of the maximal ideal of $x$ in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

In https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Multiplicity_of_a_singular_point this notion is defined and a few properties are given. From this site i quote:
"The multiplicity does not change when $X$ is cut by a generic hypersurface through $x$".

(I guess here we should assume $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$)

My question is now, what are exactly the conditions so that it *does* change? And how to prove the claim?

Any reference to the literature or just a sketch of a proof is already fine! Thanks!

Comment: Wasn't there an answer posted here already? Where did it go? I was about to check it out in detail and it seemed really useful!